# Mocking env() in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

I'm trying to test my applications ability to handle missing configuration.

How do I mock calls to env()?

I can't find any documentation in Mockery for mocking global function calls...

Comment: What `env()` variable are you trying to test? Most `.env` variables are converted to a `config()` option, like `config('app.env')` would be equivalent to `env('APP_ENV')`. Additionally, `config()` allows on the fly setting, so an approach like `config(['app.env' => null])` (to remove the setting), followed by `Assert::assertNull(config('app.env'))` (or whatever the syntax is you're using for tests) to assert that the `env` setting (via `config()`) is in fact missing.

Comment: Tim's suggestion is the way I've gone, but thank your Alex for another useful approach.